# I want to change the color of "colorButton" selected from list. (color is added by user in list)

Tags: java, swing

Here is my code. when user will select a color from list and press "show color" button then color of "show color" button should change by selected color.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class A8 extends JFrame {
JList list;
JTextField inputField;
DefaultListModel model;
 // String selected;

A8(){

    model = new DefaultListModel();
    model.addElement("RED");
    list = new JList(model);

    JButton addButton = new JButton("ADD");
    addButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                {
                    String str = inputField.getText();
                    model.addElement(str);
                }
            }
    );

    JButton colorButton = new JButton("Show Color");
     colorButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                {
                    String str = list.getSelectedValue().toString();  
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It's "+ str);
                   // JOptionPane.setBackground(color.str);
                   colorButton.setBackground(Color.str);
                }
            }
    );

   inputField=new JTextField();
     inputField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
     }
   );
   list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION );

   JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
     inputPanel.add( addButton);
     inputPanel.add(colorButton);
     colorButton.setBounds(20,50,100,20);
     inputPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(inputPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

     inputField.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     inputField.setBounds(5, 5, 100, 100);
     inputField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,20));
     JScrollPane scrollPane=new JScrollPane(list);
     scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));

     Container container = getContentPane();
     add(scrollPane);
     container.add( inputPanel);
     add( inputField);
     container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


     //container.setBackground(Color.selected);

     setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
     setSize( 500, 250 );
     setVisible( true );

 } 
   public static void main( String args[] )
         {
         new A8();
     }
}
```

Please suggest me where should i update the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
colorButton.setBackground(Color.str);
```

The above code tries to reference a variable from the Color class the doesn't exist. You can just make up a variable name that way.

One way to solve the problem is to create a HashMap of the Colors you want to support:

```
HashMap<String, Color> colors = new HashMap<String, Color>();
colors.put("RED", Color.RED);
...
```

Then in your ActionListener you can access the Color by using:

```
String str = list.getSelectedValue().toString(); 
Color color = colors.get(str);
colorButton.setBackground( color );
```